# How to reliably replace a library-defined error handler with my own?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, linker, atl

On certain error cases ATL invokes [`AtlThrow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z325eyx0(VS.80).aspx) which is implemented as `ATL::AtlThrowImpl()` which in turn throws [`CAtlException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b1a94tx(VS.80).aspx). The latter is not very good - `CAtlException` is not even derived from `std::exception` and also we use our own exceptions hierarchy and now we will have to catch `CAtlException` separately here and there which is lots of extra code and error-prone.

Looks like it is possible to replace `ATL::AtlThrowImpl()` with my own handler - define `_ATL_CUSTOM_THROW` and define `AtlThrow()` to be the custom handler before including `atlbase.h` - and ATL will call the custom handler.

Not so easy. Some of ATL code is not in sources - it comes compiled as a library - either static or dynamic. We use the static - `atls.lib`. And... it is compiled in such way that it has `ATL::ThrowImpl()` inside and some code calling it. I used a static analysis tool - it clearly shows that there're paths on which the old default handler is called.

To ensure I even tried to "reimplement" `ATL::AtlThrowImpl()` in my code. Now the linker says it sees two declarations of `ATL::AtlThrowImpl()` which I suppose confirms that there's another implementation that can be called by some code.

How can I handle this? How do I replace the default handler completely and ensure that the default handler is never called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered similar problems when writing my own memory manager and wanted to overrule malloc and free.

The problem is that ATL::AtlThrowImpl is probably part of a source file that also includes other files that are really needed.

If the linker sees a reference to a function in one of the object files, it pulls in the object file with that function, including all other functions in that same object file.

The solution is to look up in the ATL sources where ATL::AtlThrowImpl is defined and see if the source contains other functions.  You will also need to implement the other functions to prevent the linker from having any reference to the original ATL source.

Comment: You're right, but turns out the problem is AtlThrowImpl() is an inline function and those are handled specially - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aszego/archive/2010/05/12/override-atlthrow-with-care.aspx so the bottom line is current ATL design requires library recompilation to replace the handler.

Comment: Overriding inline methods this way is of course impossible.  I see no solution for that, other than to alter the headers and recompile the whole ATL library.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked these windows libraries in quite a while, but you should be able to get the linker to pick your replacement by putting it in a static library listed earlier in the link statement.  Make sure you are using the same method signature as the original. You can also play with linker flags to omit default libraries, for various definitions of default.

If you have a friend with access to MSDN, it may have some of the ATL debug sources, which also helps.

And, as Patrick says, you need to provide a replacement for everything in the same linkage scope.  Some libraries break the individual methods out into separate object files to make it easier to replace one piece.  That's more common with e.g. c standard lib than for a class. If there's a lot of ATL code capable of calling their throw impl in a single object file, it may be more pain than it is worth....you may need to try catching and rethrowing as your own type.